# Module not found: Can't resolve 'papaparse' issue

Tags: reactjs, csv, papaparse

[image]

I worked with the CSV file and tryied for the first time to work with PapaParse to parse data from CSV file into the app.

```
import Papa from 'papaparse';
 ....
 ....
useEffect(() => {
        Papa.parse('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DeveloperCircleHub/HospitalDash/master/pmd_all_contracted_legal_entities.csv', {download: true,
            header: true,
            complete: function (results) {
                setHospitalData(results.data);
                setIsLoading(false);
            }});
    }, [timer]);
```

I got problem : "Module not found"

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Do you have installed `papaparse` package in package.json file? Just run next command `npm install papaparse`

Comment: You need to [install it](https://github.com/mholt/PapaParse#install), in the directory where your package.json is execute the following command: `yarn add papaparse` or `npm install papaparse` (depending if you want to use yarn or npm as package installer).

Answer (score 0):

please run this on project console "npm install papaparse"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).